# installing node.js E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I need to install node in my system (Ubuntu 16.04) so I type:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

but I get this error:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I solved the issue myself. For anyone who comes across this problem i solved it by doing the following,
Upon a second look i noticed error was caused by a package git-daemon-run as we can clearly see in line

```
dpkg:error processing package git-daemon-run (--configure):
```

So i tried to purge it using command

```
apt-get purge remove git-daemon-run
```

But i got the same error but this time the package with error was runit so i purged it with

```
apt-get purge remove runit
```

and it worked.